# Awesomium c++: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

Tags: c++, pointers, awesomium

I'm trying to integrate c++ code with awesomium functionalities, but I get many errors.
It seems that VisualStudio doesn't like my definition/declaration of the WebCore element. I copied it from http://wiki.awesomium.com/tutorials/tutorial-1-hello-awesomium.html.
I have simplified the code until this, and I still get the errors.

SimpleClass.cpp:

```
#include <Awesomium/WebCore.h>
include "SimpleClass.h"
using namespace Awesomium;

CSimpleClass::CSimpleClass(){   
    WebCore *web_core = WebCore::Initialize(WebConfig());
}
CSimpleClass::~CSimpleClass(){
}
```

SimpleClass.h:

```
class CSimpleClass
{
public:
    CSimpleClass(void);
    ~CSimpleClass(void);
    WebCore *web_core;
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: The using namespace won't magically apply itself to your header file.

Comment: Avoid using `using namespace` in header files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `SimpleClass.h` header to read:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SIMPLECLASS_H
#define SIMPLECLASS_H

// forward declarations
namespace Awesomium{
class WebCore;
}

class CSimpleClass
{
public:
    CSimpleClass(void);
    ~CSimpleClass(void);
    Awesomium::WebCore *web_core;
};

#endif /* SIMPLECLASS_H */
```

That way you announce to your compiler that there exists a type `WebCore` in the namespace `Awesonium`, and then you can use it to declare the member pointer `CSimpleClass::web_core`.

Comment: Based on the OP's include order, the forward declaration is unnecessary because the compiler already knows about WebCore before SimpleClass.h gets included

Comment: @badgerr Ideally, a header is self-contained and doesn't rely on the include order in other files.

Comment: @badgerr true, but that include order is asking for trouble. Headers should be always self-contained, as molbdnilo pointed out. This is why in the `*.cpp` file you should always include the corresponding header *first*, and only then headers required by the implementation. Because if at some other point in your program you include the header, you're missing the `Awesomium/WebCore.h` header.

Answer (score 0):

Potential dependency issues aside, the problem is that your header does not know that you want to use the `Awesomium` namespace.

**Either** *(preferred)* be explicit in the header about your definition of *web_core by doing

```
class CSimpleClass
{
public:
    CSimpleClass(void);
    ~CSimpleClass(void);
    Awesomium::WebCore *web_core; //note the use of Awesomium::
};
```

**or** *(if you really must)* include your header after your using directive

```
#include <Awesomium/WebCore.h>
using namespace Awesomium;
#include "SimpleClass.h"
```